# Field of type "error.NonExistentClass" cannot be an @Index (Realm java)

Tags: java, android

My app complains about a field "OrderId" which is defined in a library that I maintain, which was recently upgraded.

This occurs in the KaptWithoutKotlinc task.

```
Field "orderId" of type "error.NonExistentClass" cannot be an @Index

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

Realm-java version: 6.1.0.

In my app:

```
open class Metadata : RealmObject() {    
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = "1234"
    @Index
    var orderId: OrderId = 4
```

In my library:

```
Definitions.kt

typealias OrderId = Int
```

I have already tried the following:

```
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was not a Realm error. **Downgrading the Kotlin-Gradle plugin from 1.6.0 to 1.5.0 fixed the issue**. Something about upgrading Kotlin in my library caused the typealias OrderId definition to be missing from the generated Definitions.class file that my app was pulling in from the library (I inspected this file by going to Android Studio > External Libraries> com.mylibrary > Definitions.class and seeing that OrderId was not defined there). After downgrading typealias to be present in Definitions.class, my app could resolve the OrderId typealias, and then Realm no longer considered OrderId an invalid @Index field.

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0
```